# Asus Transformer Slider frequently freezes

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, system-freeze

I am a not-so-proud owner of an Asus Slider tablet, the one with the slide-out keyboard. I find that whenever I shake the device, open the keyboard, or otherwise move the tablet, it freezes up.

I sent it into ASUS for support, but they said they did not find anything wrong with the tablet. I also tried leaving the tablet out to see if it would unfreeze, but it did not. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved these problems upgrading it. Go to Setup -> Tablet information -> Firmware update.

Using Android 4.0.3 i have no more reboots, nor freezes.

Manual downloads and instructions are available on the Asus site [here](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Slider_SL101/#download).

Comment: It dutifully reports "There is no update for your device currently."

Answer (score 0):

You could install a 3rd party aftermarket firmware like AOKP or CyanogenMod (originally intended for the TF101 model).

From what I read, one can use ROM images for the almost identical TF101 model (and maybe also flash a SL101 compatibility package on top of it that changes only some minor things (more keyboard models, sound settings, etc.). Even Asus' official update zip for the TF101 is fully compatible with the SL101.

Source: [XDA](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Slider_SL101/#download)